# iReport with a remote xml data source

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, datasource, ireport

I've been totally stuck with this for the whole day. Seems like there is not documentation out there except in paper form.

I'm using `iReport 4.5.1`.

What I'm trying to do is to create a report with a `remote xml data source`. This is what I have done so far:

- from teh Welcome page, I went to step one and made a new data source, "Remote XML file data source". I input the URL and nothing else since this is only some string data. The XML URL points to a machine on my internal network and this URL gives me xml output in a browser.
- I click Test. It seems to always report success, even if I just use the URL "http://".
- I go to step 2. I choose my dtaa source and the query text box disappears. I click next and I get no fields.

Am I not supposed to type in an `XPath` query somewhere?? I've searched all around the `iReport` user interface and can find nothing.

Curiously enough, I found a post somewhere by a guy who was having the same problem. There had been no replies to that post, even though it was posted four years ago!

I might be barking up the wrong tree with `JasperReports` in general. But this feature, to use remote XML data as a data source, is exactly what I need! By doing that, I can use my local Tomcat as a data provider and all the DB logic would be in one place.

Hope someone can help!

Gísli

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial http://www.packtpub.com/article/jasperreports-creating-report-from-xml-data-using-xpath

Just follow though the wizard and once you get to the report, click on the Query Designer (the database like icon between "preview" and the zoom icons, choose xpath2 as a query language and there you can go ahead and input your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply! The main reason for my problems was that iReport's query window was by default sized in such a way that the fields picked up from the xml were not visible. When I resized the window, I could see what was being picked up from the xml.

Also, in the beginning, I was using an xml feed that had empty lines in it which caused it to not report any fields. A bit strange though that testing the data source was always successful.

Thanks again!
  Gísli